# Castle Windsor not creating/exposing Base class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, castle-windsor, asp.net-apicontroller

I've got a few Repository classes within a Repository project that uses an Entity Framework DbContext Typed base class.

Base Class

```
public class RepositoryBase<TC> : IDisposable
    where TC : DbContext, new()
{

    public virtual T Get<T>(...) where T : class
    {
        ...
    }

    // ... additional code
}
```

Employee Repo Interface

```
namespace Insight.Repository.Interfaces
{
    public interface IEmployeeRepository
    {
        Result CreateEmployee(Employee employee);
        // ... additional code
    }
}
```

Employee Repo

```
namespace Insight.Repository.Repositories
{
    public class EmployeeRepository : RepositoryBase<InsightContext>, IEmployeeRepository
    {
        public Result CreateEmployee(Employee employee)
        {
            return Save(employee);
        }
    }
    // ... additional code
}
```

I am adding the Repo classes to the Windsor container within an Asp.Mvc website using an installer based on Interfaces within the Repository project. I've looked at the container at this point and I'm getting my three repositories.

```
public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(Classes.FromAssemblyNamed("Insight.Repository")
           .Where(Component.IsInNamespace("Insight.Repository.Repositories"))
            .WithService.DefaultInterfaces()
            .LifestyleTransient());
    }
```

I've tried registering the DbContext as follows but I get the same results.

```
container.Register(Component.For<DbContext>()
            .ImplementedBy<InsightContext>()
            .LifestyleTransient());
```

Then, within my ApiController, I'm then using Property injection to instantiate the Repo class but I can't get access any of the base class functions.

```
public class EmployeeController : ApiController
{
    public IEmployeeRepository EmployeeRepo { get; set; }

    [Route("GetEmployee")]
    public void Get()
    {
        var newEmployeeRepo = new EmployeeRepository();
    }
}
```

EmployeeRepo doesn't have access to the Get() function in the base class but newEmployeeRepo does.

This is my first project using Castle.Windsor and I am clearly missing some sort of registration step but can figure it out.

If someone can point me in the right direction, much appreciated.

Edit: Testing with the Linqpad code supplied by tym32167

```
void Main()
{
    var container = new WindsorContainer();

    var type = typeof(II);
    container.Register(Classes.FromAssembly(type.Assembly)
       .Where(Component.IsInNamespace(type.Namespace))
        .WithService.AllInterfaces()
        .LifestyleTransient());

    var cls = container.Resolve<II>().Dump();
    cls.GetFirstName().Dump();
    cls.GetLastName().Dump();
}

public interface II
{
    string GetFirstName();
}

public class MyClass : II
{
    public string GetFirstName()
    {
    return "First Name";
    }

    public string GetLastName()
    {
    return "Last Name";
    }
}
```

The code breaks on this line:

```
cls.GetLastName().Dump();
```

Is this the expected behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get access to the methods on the base class, you need to have a base interface :)

```
public interface IBaseRepo<T>
{
     T Get(int id);
     // ...
}

public interface IEmployeeRepo : IBaseRepo<Employee>
{
     Employee GetByFirstName(string name);
     // ...
}
```

Note how the child interface inherits the base interface. Thus, any type implementing `IEmployeeRepo` guarantees that it also implements `IBaseRepo<Employee>`, and when you inject one you get access to the methods on the base interface too.

The fact that you implement the base repo in a base class, that your concrete employee repo inherits, is just an implementation detail that the client code shouldn't have to care about - and now it doesn't!

Comment: Well, if you put it like that, it sounds so obvious. Thanks, that solution worked a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
.WithService.DefaultInterfaces()
```

to

```
.WithService.AllInterfaces()
```

as sample (just checked with linqpad)

```
void Main()
{   
    var container = new WindsorContainer();

    var type = typeof(II);
    container.Register(Classes.FromAssembly(type.Assembly)
           .Where(Component.IsInNamespace(type.Namespace))
            .WithService.AllInterfaces()
            .LifestyleTransient());

    container.Resolve<II>().Dump();
}

public interface II
{
}

public class MyCl : II
{
}
```

Comment: I made the change as suggested but it only seemed to pick up the additional IDisposable interface from the RepositoryBase class.
Looking at the container after registration, **EmployeeRepository / IEmployeeRepository = Transient** has changed to **EmployeeRepository / IEmployeeRepository and 1 other services = Transient** within the components of the container and I have an additional **IDisposable** entry within the Services of the container.
It's still not resolving the base class functionality.

Comment: are you using webapi, right? Are you implement all nececarry relates stuff, like dependencyresolver/dependency scope? Once I created basic sample with castle windsor, check this please https://github.com/tym32167/webapisample (especially global.asax.cs and Core folder here https://github.com/tym32167/webapisample/tree/master/src/Sample/Core )

Comment: by the way, constructor injection much better than property injection, because 1. You can see all dependencies in one place - ctor arguments, 2. - in any problems with resolving you will get runtime exception with message and stack trace

Comment: I added a dependency resolver to my site within the Global.asax as per your example site but it didn't make any difference.
I think I'm missing the boat completely. I tested the problem with the code you supplied from LinqPad and I'm getting the same result.
It seems that the container only exposes the functions from the Interface when it resolves to a concrete class. I've edited my original question with the code I used in LinqPad. It breaks on cls.GetLastName().Dump().

Comment: But you have not GetLastName in II interface in your example. Thats why it does not compile..

Comment: Ahh, I start understanding your problem. You are trying resolve II interface and only II interface will acessed - this is logical. If you want to see any additional members, you should to extend interface.

Comment: Yes, I thought that it would instantiate all the members of the class as the class is registered in the container as the implementation of the interface but it only creates a instance with the members of the Interface.
Thanks for all your help though.